# Assigning values to list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to keep track of something with 5 categories and 10 subcategories each. Each item is described with a 0 or a 1. I decided to make a list of lists in the following format:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]...]
```

When trying to assign a value to only one of these sub-lists, the code assign it to all the sub-lists.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
categories=['a','b','c','d','e','f']

status=[]
zeros=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in categories:
    status.append(zeros)

print(status)

category=0
subcategory=1

status[category][subcategory] = 2

print(status)
```

result:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I want the program to only edit one list at a time but instead if edits all the subcategories. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You've appended the same list (originally named `zeroes`) to your `status` list multiple times. That is, it has n references to the same underlying object, so when you mutate it you see the mutations in each of those references.

You want to make an independent copy of `zeroes` each time you append it, or build a new object each time. Because it contains only integer values a shallow copy is fine, you can get one of those with the slice operator `[:]`:

```
for i in categories:
    status.append(zeros[:])
```

If your list might contain references to mutable objects, you'd want to use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) built in module instead of a complete slice. `copy.copy()` is a shallow copy and therefore equivalent to slicing, so that's an acceptable option here if you prefer it but `[:]` is the more common Python idiom. `copy.deepcopy()` would handle mutable types, such as if you wanted to copy `status` after creating it with independent sublists.

Or you can make a new list of zeroes:

```
for i in categories:
    status.append([0] * num_subcategories)
```

Note that that last idiom shallow copies as well, making a list of `num_subcategories` identical references to the single element of the list. That's fine here, but a common way to get into the situation you were originally in if you use it to expand a list of lists. Don't do this if you're expecting independent lists:

```
list_of_lists = [[]] * n
```

Also don't do this:

```
status = [zeroes] * num_categories
```

I mention this because it's so closely related to your original problem, and a common way to try to set up a two-dimension array.

Comment: Thanks. I used the first method and it solved the issue. I didn't know it was appending the same object.